# javascript selection sort causing chrome browser console to hang or crash why?

Tags: javascript, sorting, console, selection-sort

Why is the console crashing in my browser, if I run this function in a variable in the browser console, it hangs or crashes, I can close the tab but the console just stops working.

```
let arr=[70,30,24,90,4];

function selectionSort(list){
    let minIndex=0;
    let minVal=0;

    for(let i=0; list.length; i++){
        minIndex=i;
        minVal=list[i];

        for(let j=i; j<list.length; j++){
            if(list[i]< minVal){
                minVal=list[i];
                minIndex=j;

            }
        }
        if(minVal<list[i]){
            temp=list[i];
            list[i]=list[minIndex];
            list[minIndex]=temp;
        }
    }


    return list;
}

let ar= selectionSort(arr);// causes console in chrome to stop working
```

Comment: Why don't you use Array native sort function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code had a couple of issues, it's working like this

```js
let arr = [70, 30, 24, 90, 4, 23];

function selectionSort(list) {
  let minIndex = 0;
  let minVal = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) { // add "i < " to prevent infinite loop
    minIndex = i;
    minVal = list[i];

    for (let j = i+1; j < list.length; j++) { // add "+1" (saves you a nano second)
      if (list[j] < minVal) { // change to j (otherwise the sorting won't work)
        minVal = list[j];
        minIndex = j;
      }
    }
    
    if (minVal < list[i]) {
      let temp = list[i];
      list[i] = list[minIndex];
      list[minIndex] = temp;
    }
    
  }

}

selectionSort(arr)
console.log(arr)
```

Keep in mind that JavaScript is call is call by reference on arrays. So do not assign list to a new variable.

Answer (score 1):

Infinite loop.

You need

```
for(let i=0; i < list.length; i++){
```

otherwise list.length is always true-ish.

Also bear in mind you are reinventing wheel:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to have a custom sorting while you can use `sort()` method:

```js
let arr=[70,30,24,90,4, 400, 0, 24];
let sorted = arr.sort((a, b) => a > b );

console.log(sorted);
```

Your browser hangs because of the nested loops and the checks you are having.